# SwiftUI Charts combined area and line Mark, with different colours for each series and mark

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-charts

I'm trying to create a Line chart with two lines (series) and the area beneath each line filled with a gradient colour. This works when there is only one line or when the line and area marks have the same colour. However, when I try to use a different colour for the line and area marks then it produces strange results.

I tried to separate out the different Area series, it didn't work.

```
Chart(data.chartData) { series in
            ForEach(Array(series.chartData), id: \.self) { element in
                    LineMark(
                        x: .value("Date", element.date),
                        y: .value("Performance", element.value)
                    )
                    .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1))
                    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Name", series.name))
                }
                if series.type == .type1 {
                    AreaMark(
                        x: .value("Date", element.date),
                        y: .value("Performance", element.value)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(areaGradient)
                } else if series.type == .index {
                    AreaMark(
                        x: .value("Date", element.date),
                        y: .value("Performance", element.value)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(areaIndexGradient)
                }
            }
        }
        .chartForegroundStyleScale(range: [.green, .orange)
```

This is a full working example:

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct PData: Codable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var chartData: [Performance]
}
struct Performance: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var type: SeriesType
    var chartData: [PerformanceValue]
}

struct PerformanceValue: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var date: Date
    var value: Double
}
enum SeriesType: Codable {
    case type1, index
}

struct Example: View {
    
    let areaGradient = LinearGradient(
            gradient: Gradient (
                colors: [
                    Color.green.opacity(0.5),
                    Color.green.opacity(0.2),
                    Color.green.opacity(0.05),
                    Color.green.opacity(0.00)
                ]
            ),
            startPoint: .top,
            endPoint: .bottom
        )

    let areaIndexGradient = LinearGradient(
        gradient: Gradient (
            colors: [
                Color.orange.opacity(0.5),
                Color.orange.opacity(0.2),
                Color.orange.opacity(0.05),
                Color.orange.opacity(0.00)
            ]
        ),
        startPoint: .top,
        endPoint: .bottom
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let series1 = Performance(name: "Series 1", type: .index, chartData: generatePerformanceValues())
        let series2 = Performance(name: "Series 2", type: .type1, chartData: generatePerformanceValues())
        let data = PData(name: "Chart Date", chartData: [series2, series1])

        VStack {
            Chart(data.chartData) { series in
                ForEach(series.chartData) { element in
                    LineMark(
                        x: .value("Date", element.date),
                        y: .value("Performance", element.value)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Name", series.name))
                    if series.type == .type1 {
                        AreaMark(
                            x: .value("Date", element.date),
                            y: .value("Performance", element.value)
                        )
                        .foregroundStyle(areaGradient)
                    } 
                    else if series.type == .index {
                        AreaMark(
                            x: .value("Date", element.date),
                            y: .value("Performance", element.value)
                        )
                        .foregroundStyle(areaIndexGradient)
                    }
                }
            }
            .chartForegroundStyleScale(range: [.green, .orange])
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func generatePerformanceValues() -> [PerformanceValue] {
        var performanceValues: [PerformanceValue] = []
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        
        var value = 3.0 // Starting value
        
        for month in 0..<50 {
            let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: month, to: Date())!
            
            // Add a small random increment or decrement to the value
            let change = Double.random(in: -0.2...0.2)
            value += change
            
            // Clamp the value between 1 and 5
            value = min(max(value, 1), 5)
            
            let performanceValue = PerformanceValue(date: date, value: value.rounded(toPlaces: 2))
            performanceValues.append(performanceValue)
        }
        
        return performanceValues
    }
}

extension Double {
    func rounded(toPlaces places: Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

Comment: show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The bits of code you show cannot be compiled, cannot be executed, cannot be tested.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Updated to include a full working example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes strange results. You could try this approach using an extra `.foregroundStyle(by:...)`,
and `.foregroundStyle(series.type == .type1 ? areaGradient : areaIndexGradient)` instead of the
`if series.type == .type1 {...} ...`. Seems to work for me.

```
VStack {
    Chart(data.chartData) { series in
        ForEach(series.chartData) { element in
            LineMark(
                x: .value("Date", element.date),
                y: .value("Performance", element.value)
            )
            
            AreaMark(
                x: .value("Date", element.date),
                y: .value("Performance", element.value)
            )
            .foregroundStyle(series.type == .type1 ? areaGradient : areaIndexGradient)
        }
        .foregroundStyle(by: .value("", series.type == .type1 ? 0 : 1))
    }
    .chartForegroundStyleScale(range: [.green, .orange])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately this also removes the LineMark from display. Do you understand what the extra foregroundStyle does?

Comment: ha yes, try removing the `.foregroundStyle(by: .value("Name", series.name))` attached to the `LineMark`. I'll update my answer with that.

Comment: thanks, yes that works :)
Any idea how to get the area marks to stack, so that the gradients don't merge into each other?

Comment: if my answer helped, please consider accepting it by ticking the tick mark next to it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the merging seems to be the result of the gradients.
 If you had specific colors, for example `.foregroundStyle(series.type == .type1 ? .green : .orange)`
 the `AreaMark` would look stacked (assuming the data allows it).
 Alternatively you could adjust the data of the series,
 such that the data values of one series is "added" to the other before charting.
 You could also look at the different variants of `chartForegroundStyleScale(...)`.